# What are the different ways you can communicate with USB port through Browser

Tags: web, usb, communication

I want to create a webpage that will access the USB port of the client. Intent is to configure the hardware connected the USB port. I can do a desktop application because the configuration option is different for different hardware. connected and I need to pull this code dynamically from the server. I am not a web programmer. It will great to find the best way to do this.

Comment: Web browsers are typically isolated from the hardware layer for security reasons. You may need to write an applet instead of doing it through a browser.

Comment: I can't wait to read the justification for this!

Comment: Is applet the only way to do it. many people that I spoken to have suggested to create a python based local server. What will be the pros and cons to use applets. Can all the web genius teach us the best way to accomplish this ?

Comment: Is there anyone that can help us with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It ends up that I am attempting to write an app that performs something similar. What I am doing, instead is writing both the web server and the web page. Use something simple, like DLib for the web server, to serve the data to the end user.

This is how it works:
The web server handles the USB connection. If written in C++ or some other native language, you will have much more control over the device. The web page is then loaded from the web server that you have written. In the web page, you can have some sort of javascript worker, etc. to constantly pull new data from the server and push data from the web interface to the USB device. This also adds a layer of protection because you can ensure that the user has not made any modifications to the web page.

The main drawback to this possibility is that you will be required to install the server on the client's machine. However, this can be circumvented by writing this as a applet that can be embedded within the page!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to write a browser plugin that communicates with USB devices.  An example of an app that does that is [MyTrezor.com](http://mytrezor.com), but unfortunately I don't think you can see the source of their plugin.

Another option might be to use the [chrome.usb](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/usb) or [chrome.serial](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/serial) Javascript API, but this means your app would only work in Google Chrome, and it would have to be installed as a [Chrome packaged app](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps), a special thing that looks more like a native app than a web page.